# How to mirror DDL changes from one schema to other?

Tags: oracle, triggers, ddl

I have a requirement to keep the structure of archive table same as the main table. Whenever we perform some DDL on main table, i want same DDL on the archive table as well. Please suggest how can i implement it in Oracle DB.

Consider below scenario where i have 2 tables A.T1_TAB and B.T1_TAB_ARCH.
I am adding a column (NAME VARCHAR2(30)) to A.T1_TAB. I need the same column to be added in B.T1_TAB_ARCH.

```
--SCHEMA B:
CREATE TABLE T1_TAB_ARCH(ID NUMBER);
--SCHEMA A:
CREATE TABLE T1_TAB(ID NUMBER);

ALTER TABLE T1_TAB ADD NAME VARCHAR2(30);--Added column in A.T1_TAB
```

Can we do it using DDL triggers or any other way.

Also i want this functionality to be enabled only for a set of tables that i have stored in a separate lookup table.

Thanks
K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you my trigger that writes every single DDL on my database. I am using this trigger when I have to test a database performance before a migration. This helps me to keep the second database up to date. I have a lot of information in this table, last database I used for had 50TB and over 200 users.

```
CREATE TABLE SESSION_DDLS
(
  SID           NUMBER,
  SERIAL        NUMBER,
  USERNAME      VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  OSUSER        VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  MACHINE       VARCHAR2(64 BYTE),
  IP_ADDR       VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  PROCESS       VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
  PROGRAM       VARCHAR2(48 BYTE),
  MODULE        VARCHAR2(48 BYTE),
  LOGON_TIME    DATE,
  DATE_CREATED  DATE,
  OWNER         VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  OBJECT_NAME   VARCHAR2(128 BYTE),
  OBJECT_TYPE   VARCHAR2(18 BYTE),
  EVENT         VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  SQL_TEXT      VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER session_ddls
    BEFORE DDL
    ON DATABASE
DECLARE
    v_sid      NUMBER;
    sql_text   ora_name_list_t;
    stmt       VARCHAR2 ( 1000 ) := '';
    n          BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT sid
      INTO v_sid
      FROM sys.v_$mystat;

    n := NVL ( ora_sql_txt ( sql_text ), 0 );

    FOR i IN 1 .. n
    LOOP
        stmt := SUBSTR ( stmt || sql_text ( i ), 1, 1000 );
    END LOOP;

    IF LOWER ( stmt ) LIKE '%identified by%' THEN
        stmt := SUBSTR ( stmt, 1, 20 );
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO o2o.session_ddls
        SELECT vses.sid,
               vses.serial#,
               vses.username,
               vses.osuser,
               vses.machine,
               SYS_CONTEXT ( 'userenv', 'ip_address' ),
               vses.process,
               vses.program,
               vses.module,
               vses.logon_time,
               SYSDATE,
               sys.dictionary_obj_owner,
               sys.dictionary_obj_name,
               sys.dictionary_obj_type,
               sys.sysevent,
               stmt
          FROM sys.v_$session vses
         WHERE vses.sid = v_sid;
END;
/
```

I think this is a good start for you. First of all you have to filter after DICTIONARY_OBJ_TYPE because you are interested about tables, second of all, you can implement some filters on DICTIONARY_OBJ_OWNER and DICTIONARY_OBJ_NAME and finally, if you want, you can execute the statement from SYSEVENT on your ARCH table, but don't forget to concatenate your ARCH suffix at the DICTIONARY_OBJ_NAME.

If I didn't made myself clear, please let me know.

Good luck!